# Embedding Keen Dashboard to Web Applications

Tags: javascript, keen-io

I have created a dashboard in Keen and I want to use the same dashboard in my web application. Is there any way a complete dashboard can be embedded in another application?

Iframe won't work due to crossorigin restriction. Using javascript to create widgets of a dashboard is a solution but I wanted to skip the coding part of it. Reason for this is because if my client wants to update the dashboard then he can do so by simply updating it on keen and new build should not be required for such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Keen and you're correct that the iframe won’t work, because of the security changes introduced to the browsers to stop clickjacking attacks.

In the first iteration of “embed html” we used a static version of the properties used to store your json (which contains info about the charts to render and the names of saved queries to use).

We're working on deploying the updated version of the dashboard-viewer - which supports dynamic loading of the current state of the dashboard.
This should solve the issue you're referencing. If you would like to submit a ticket on our website would could provide a time as it get's closer to launch. Just reference this url.

https://responsivedesign.is/articles/xframe-options/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options